# libv4l2: error turning on stream: Invalid argument VIDIOC_STREAMON: Invalid argument

Tags: 14.04, webcam, streaming, camera, opencv

I'm working on camera using opencv 3.0.0 and C++ with Ubuntu 14.04 ,

When I run a program using the camera and stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, I can't get it run for a second time and it gives me the following:

```
libv4l2: error turning on stream: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Invalid argument
Cannot read a frame from video stream
```

I have tried `lsusb` and the camera (it's built in in laptop not external) is not recognized. Also with cheeze it tells me that there is an error when trying to open the camera.

The only solution is to reboot the laptop.

Any suggestion will be appreciated :) thanks

Answer (score 3):

This occure when **camera is not released by your program** - for example when you kill it using <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>. You can use custom way to exit camera reading loop - for example wait for <kbd>Esc</kbd>:

```
while (1) { // camera loop
    cap.read(frame);
    ...
    (frame processing)
    ...
    if (waitKey(20) == 27) { // wait for 'Esc' key press for 20ms
        break; //  if 'Esc' key is pressed, break loop
    }
}
```

**Or better, you can catch <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> (SIGINT signal):**

```
bool stop = false;

void sigIntHandler(int signal) {
    stop = true;
}


std::signal(SIGINT, sigIntHandler);

while (!stop) { // camera loop
    cap.read(frame);
    ...
    (frame processing)
    ...
}
```

See: [Signal handling in C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal)

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention your platform, but on the Raspberry Pi, this error can occur when running video capture using the v4l2 driver and when GPU memory is not set at 128 MB or greater. Run `sudo raspi-config` and adjust it to 128 using the menu.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with the kernel

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

This has done the trick for me